# Why does the siunitx LaTeX package add a vertical offset to some text elements in matplotlib figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm using LaTeX to render text in my matplotlib figures. When I add the package siunitx to my LaTeX preamble, some text elements are no longer vertically aligned correctly.

I've only encountered this problem recently: figures which were previously rendered correctly are now broken. It affects multiple python environments, so I believe it may be due to a recent version of siunitx?

Here is my minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Test data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 64)
y = np.sin(x)

# Use latex for text
plt.rcdefaults()
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

# Correctly behaving text
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax0.plot(x, y, label='some string')
ax0.legend()
fig0.tight_layout()
fig0.savefig('without_siunitx.png')
plt.show()

# Use siunitx
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\n'.join([
    r'\usepackage{siunitx}',
])

# Now some text has incorrect y position
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y, label='some string')
ax1.legend()
fig1.tight_layout()
fig1.savefig('with_siunitx.png')
plt.show()
```

For the minimum working example I'm using python 3.8.12, matplotlib 3.3.2 and siunitx 3.0.32 (installed via MiKTeX) on Windows 10.

The two png images generated are linked below:

[image: Correctly aligned figure without siunitx]

[image: Incorrectly aligned figure with siunitx]

You can see that the legend text and the y-axis tick labels are misaligned after using siunitx.

I'll be really grateful to anybody who can help me solve this issue, as it affects most of the figures for my thesis. Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you try with `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That fixed it, thanks so much! Could I ask what the square brackets are doing here? This is my first stackoverflow question, is there some way I can mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: That's the latex syntax to roll back to a previous version, see https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2018-FMi-TUB-tb122mitt-version-rollback.pdf for details

Comment: That's great, cheers for your help.

Comment: This does not happen here --- I have `Matplotlib:  3.1.2`, `Numpy 1.17.4` and `siunitx v3.0.33`. The two diagrams are the same... (Linux Ubuntu, but I have LaTeX installed independently).

Comment: To help debugging, you shoud have somewhere a matplotlib cache directory --- https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html cites that in troubleshooting --- and you can find the LaTeX file there. Clean the directory, run it and you can find the LaTeX sources there.

Comment: If you can find the LaTeX files that are failing/creating the problem, you maybe can help by posting them (and this problem here) on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ --- the author of `siunitx` is very active there.

Comment: What happens if you load `\usepackage{color}` instead of siunitx. Does this displace the text too?

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, I'll post there soon with the tex.cache files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, color causes the same effect.

Comment: @Rmano I've posted another question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619652/using-some-packages-adds-a-vertical-offset-when-using-latex-to-render-text-in-ma , cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it worked correctly before, you can rollback to version 2 of siunitx with the following syntax:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]
```